# What's the benefit of encapsulating only one basic field into a struct in C?

Tags: c, struct, typedef

I saw some C code like this:

```
// A:
typedef uint32_t in_addr_t;
struct in_addr { in_addr_t s_addr; };
```

And I always prefer like this:

```
// B:
typedef uint32_t in_addr;
```

So my question is: what's the difference / benefit of doing it in A from B?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a layer to introduce type safety, and it can be helpful 'for future expansion'.

One problem with the former is that it's easy to 'convert' a value of a type represented by a typedefed builtin to any of several other types or typedefed builtins.

consider:

```
typedef int t_millisecond;
typedef int t_second;
typedef int t_degrees;
```

versus:

```
// field notation could vary greatly here:
struct t_millisecond { int ms; };
struct t_second { int s; };
struct t_degrees { int f; };
```

In some cases, it makes it a little clearer to use a notation, and the compiler will also forbid erroneous conversions. Consider:

```
int a = millsecond * second - degree;
```

this is a suspicious program. using typedefed ints, that's a valid program. Using structs, it's ill-formed -- compiler errors will require your corrections, and you can make your intent explicit.

Using typedefs, arbitrary arithmetic and conversions may be applied, and they may be assigned to each other without warning, which can can become a burden to maintain.

Consider also:

```
t_second s = millisecond;
```

that would also be a fatal conversion.

It's just another tool in the toolbox -- use at your discretion.

Comment: For the safety, do you mean that's for avoiding of some mistake type casting? For the expansion, I prefer to change a simple typedef to a struct when I'd really mean to do that.

Comment: +1 Right but I'm not sure he'll understand without examples! :)

Comment: @paladin_t: If you assign a float value to an `uint32_t` it would with some warnings, do the assignment. However, this is impossible with a struct.

Comment: @paladin_t I think the "for future expansion" was not just "expand the value" but "expand the types of data collected", i.e., be able to have an API which began expanding the struct to maintain metadata associated with requests without requiring the interface itself to change. I've also used the "single member of a struct" to allow me to add/remove debugging data invisibly to the code that was poking the interface I was providing.

Comment: @paladin_t expanded. not type-casting, acceptable implicit conversions due to the underlying type being the same.

Comment: @Adriano was expanding. examples added

Answer (score 2):

Justin's answer is essentially correct, but I think some expansion is needed:
EDIT: Justin expanded his answer significantly, which makes this one somewhat redundant.

Type safety - you want to provide your users with API functions which manipulate the data, not let it just treat it as an integer. Hiding the field in a structure makes it harder to use it the wrong way, and pushes the user towards the proper API.

For future expansion - perhaps a future implementation would like to change things. Maybe add a field, or break the existing field into 4 chars. With a struct, this can be done without changing APIs.

What's *your* benefit? That your code won't break if implementation changes.